# What is the behavior of str.isalnum() for files open in binary mode? Is it independent of locale()?

Tags: string, python-2.7, file, alphanumeric

I want to write a python2.7 program to open a file in binary mode and collect all the alpha-numeral characters/bytes based on the ASCII table values. I want this program to work for any file extension, which is why I am opening the files in binary mode. I am not using any specific encoding since I do not want a codec error.

```
def get_alnum_from_file(filename):
    res = set()
    with open(filename, "rb") as myfile:
        text = myfile.read()
            for ch in text:
                if ch.isalnum():
                    res.add(ch)
    return res
```

This has worked for all the inputs I have worked on. However, is there an edge case where ch.isalnum() will return true for characters not a-z A-Z 0-9?

For example, if it encounters characters like á, é, í, ó, ú; will it return true on some occasions? The documentation states that isalnum() depends on the locale, but I am not sure if this counts if the characters are raw binary.

Comment: Characters are never in raw binary. You always have to encode or decode the bits in some way to even consider them characters or numbers or whatever that's not pure bits.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex So what does it mean to open a file in binary mode? What is each byte being encoded to/from? I'm guessing ASCII? And if so, wouldn't that cause codec errors in some cases?

Comment: Generally, it means that line ending characters aren't handled specially in Windows, which uses two characters for a newline (CR and LF) rather than just one. This screws up binary formats, since a byte can essentially vanish if there's a CRLF (and perhaps similar things) when reading and can appear out of nothing if you're writing the same bytes as a newline.